# Laravel Ui bootstrap, bootstrap is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a new laravel project `laravel new project`

And installed bootstrap ui like so:

```
php artisan ui bootstrap
```

Then compiled with :

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

But when I use `bootstrap` inside app.js like so :

```
require('./bootstrap');

var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'));
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
});
```

The console shows the following error :

```
app.js?e348:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: bootstrap is not defined
    at eval (app.js?e348:5:5)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at eval (app.js?e348:4:38)
    at Object../resources/assets/js/app.js (app.js:973:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:1060:42)
    at app.js:1214:86
    at Function.__webpack_require__.O (app.js:1097:23)
    at app.js:1217:53
    at app.js:1219:12
```

I've to mention that I run `npm run dev` after making changes in any resource file, and I know about `npm run watch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem this way:

In `resources/js/bootstrap.js` file :

```
window._ = require('lodash');

try {
    window.$ = require('jquery');
    window.bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
```

**Notice:** Pay attention to the line `window.bootstrap = require('bootstrap');`